# Socks set_default_proxy throws an error on Ubuntu but not on OSX or Windows

Tags: python, ubuntu, socks

Here is the part of my code that is causing the error. It runs fine on OSX and Windows.

```
def sslwrap(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def bar(*args, **kw):
        kw['ssl_version'] = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1
        return func(*args, **kw)
    return bar
ssl.wrap_socket = sslwrap(ssl.wrap_socket)
if sys.platform == "darwin":
    requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 4050)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
```

And here is the error I get on my Ubuntu server:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "new.py", line 42, in
>   
>       socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'set_default_proxy'

Any ideas as to what is going on? Is it most likely a bug in the sockspy library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the function `socks.set_default_proxy(...)` was recently renamed; previous versions of the library spelled it without underscores, as `socks.setdefaultproxy(...)`. It's likely one of these previous versions is installed on your Ubuntu server.

You can *sometimes* work around this by sort of issue by trying both spellings of the function name, as in:

```
try:
  sdp = socks.set_default_proxy
except AttributeError:
  sdp = socks.setdefaultproxy
sdp(socks.SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 4050)
```

Emphasis on sometimes; this might not be enough on its own, since the API for SocksiPy looks to have changed substantially over time and a series of different maintainers.

Source: consulting the [PySocks README](https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks), the [socksipy-x README](https://github.com/brendoncrawford/socksipy-x), and a couple before it.